# Try out new compose experince in gmail

Tags: gmail

How to get the gmail new compose experience if  'Try out new compose experience' is not available ?

Answer (score 2):

It's already the default for users.

> Gmail's new compose now default
>
> You are busy people, so it's no surprise that an overwhelming number
>   of you opted to try out Gmail's faster, simpler compose experience
>   after it launched last October. In addition to telling us what you
>   love about the new compose experience (like how much easier it is to
>   multitask!) you’ve also been sending us helpful suggestions for what
>   features you'd like to see added. As a result of your input, we're now
>   ready to introduce the new compose experience as the default for
>   everyone. We're looking forward to hearing what you think!
>
> If you're already using the the new compose experience, you've
>   probably noticed it's gotten a lot of upgrades over the last few
>   months, from a new way to send files with Google Drive to
>   much-requested features like pop-out replies. We’ve also added support
>   for originally missing features like starring and labeling when
>   composing and the Canned Responses lab.
>
> The new compose will be rolling out to everyone over the next few
>   days. You can learn more in our help center, or follow us on Google+,
>   where we'll be posting more tips for using the new compose.

[Source](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2013/03/gmails-new-compose-now-default.html)

Comment: ...unfortunately.